# How to update Tkinter Label widget?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

Here is my code so far:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

num1 = IntVar()
num2 = IntVar()

total = IntVar()
total.set(num1.get() + num2.get())

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable = num1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable = num2)
entry2.pack()

total_label = Label(root, textvariable = total)
total_label.pack()
```

What I'm trying to do is to have `total_label` always show the sum of `num1` and `num2`. However, when I run the code, `total_label` remains `0`.

How do I have `total_label` show the sum of `num1` and `num2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use trace on num1 and num2:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

num1 = IntVar()
num2 = IntVar()
total = IntVar()
def update_total(*severalignoredargs):
    total.set(num1.get() + num2.get())

num1.trace('w',update_total)
num2.trace('w',update_total)


entry1 = Entry(root,textvariable=num1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry(root,textvariable=num2)
entry2.pack()

total_label = Label(root,textvariable=total)
total_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the `trace` function, and I'll have to look into its other uses.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is call a trace method on your text variable. like num.trace('w',fun)
where fun is the function to be called whenever the value of num changes. inside the fun function, you can update the value of total. Look at the full [tkinter label](https://rawpython.com/tkinter-label/) tutorial.